# Bangla font problem in blogger.com?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, fonts

Could please anyone confirm me that the bangla fonts in any blogger site  render correctly or incorrectly in their Ubuntu 14.04?

Bangla fonts appear correctly in facebook.com and techtunes.com.bd but appear incorrectly in blogger.com (.blogspot) sites. This is the same case for both Google chrome and Firefox.

Please suggest any possible fix.

Comment: If the fonts are rendering properly in one website and not in another, how is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @ron I don't know but maybe it's somehow related to the manner with which ubuntu handle the browsers because in windows, the .blogspot websites render bangla fonts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1.First Download a standard Bangla font, such as Solaiman Lipi.

2.Install the font by copying it to either your user specific `~/.fonts` folder or for system-wide effect in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` folder.

3.Then close (if it is opened) and open the Google chrome.

4.Go to Settings, click on Advanced settings, in Website content section, click on the customize fonts button.

5.In the `sans-serif font` section, change the font to `Solaiman Lipi.`

This should solve the problem.

Comment: hello orvi! did you see the blog? do the fonts appear correctly in your browser? i've tried this method but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes , In my browser everything works so perfect.